# How to get HTML DIV value

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I'm trying to do screen shot paste in my website using firefox. It can be done easily by giving the div as `contenteditable='true'`.

**html**

```
<Html>
<Head>
<Title>Screen Shot Example</Title>
<style type="text/css">
#apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:258px;
    height:165px;
    z-index:1;
    left: 71px;
    top: 59px;
}
</style>
</Head>

<Body>
<div id="apDiv1" contenteditable='true'>Paste Test</div>
</Body>
</Html>
```

I can paste images from clipboard to particular div. Now the issue starts, how do I get the value from the div. For an example my user paste screenshot in the div and i want it to be save in db. If it normal textbox I can get the textbox value. Is there any way I can convert the DIV to image. Any advice and any referral links is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    var text = document.getElementById('apDiv1').innerText;
}, false);
```

To replace the `div`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
    var el = document.getElementById("apDiv1");
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute('src', '...');
    el.parentNode.replaceChild(el, img);
}, false);
```

Comment: does the second code change the DIV to image. Where did the image saved. Let say i way it saved in C drive automatically.

Comment: the second snippet changes the div element to an img element.

Comment: how do i get the img element and save automatically in specific folder? and the javascripts throw 'NotFoundError: Node was not found' at el.parentNode.replaceChild(el, img);

Comment: what's the reason for the downvote?! you can't save an image in html to a directory on a local machine. it's a web page, not a desktop application. ***remove the downvote***

Comment: The javascripts throw 'NotFoundError: Node was not found' at el.parentNode.replaceChild(el, img); I can't remove my downvote. Need you to edit the answer.